# Artificial Gravity Supermax

Tags: technology, moons, prison, artificial-gravity

Set 50 years in the future.

A supermax or super maximum security prison is a lockup facility to hold dangerous criminals, most of them are being sentenced for at least 1000 years of life imprisonment without parole. Recently in the news there is a plan to convert our moon into a supermax by converting it into a hollow sphere with it's interior filled with just cells and the inmates, the idea is to place them in complete isolation and also to act as a deterrence... most importantly it helps to solve overcrowding issues here on Earth ;D

Anyway there will be a space port and a small lunar base for the security personnel on shift on the Moon, the interior of the moon is partitioned up so each and every 2 cubic meters quarter can hold 1 inmate. Everything goes according to plan until the human rights group issued an ultimatum; give them at least 1g or shut down the entire facility! I'm wondering how can I replicate gravitational acceleration of minimum 9.81 meters per second per second for all the occupants? The authority and banks cannot loan us any more money and has blocked our crowdfunding websites so there is a budget constraint, in other words we are left with no investor and only 20 millions USD in cash flow to get it done!

Comment: Could you tell us about the state of the art technology available to you, how much 20 million US Dollars might be worth in your world?

Comment: If it's anything like the present day, $20 million buys you about one rocket launch... and the only way to generate gravity would be to increase the spin rate of *the whole moon*, which is not exactly a budget operation!

Comment: You can't.
----------

There's no way to do it with a budget of just 20 million and a tech level equivalent to that anticipated by 2070. 

That much money wouldn't pay for one multi-crewed trip/extended stay let alone kick start the entire project.

Then in order to achieve the desired level of Gs you'd have to 'spin' the moon along its polar axis at a velocity high enough to create 1g of centrifugal force at the equator. This gives you a very, very narrow 'donut' of '1g' on the ceiling of a cavern running along the equators circumference (and no-where else).

Comment: Part (B); You also can't do this overnight, the forces required are too great. You'd have to figure out some way of doing it over decades/centuries.

Then you have to hope the moon didn't slowly disintegrate under the internal stress - which in case it wasn't obvious would have some slightly 'adverse' consequences for the folks back home.

Comment: Potential second human rights issue, you state "the idea is to place them in complete isolation and also to act as a deterrence". Does this mean solitary confinement with no human socialization within the prison? If so, everyone will develop a significant mental illness. I can already envisage the demands to shut it down.

Comment: Moon volume is about 21.9 billion cubic kilometers, which translates to about 11 quintillion inmate cells. How many inmates do you actually have?

Comment: @Mon re Part (B) - it doesn't matter how slowly you spin up, the moon will start to disintegrate as soon as the centrifugal force exceeds the gravitational pull.  The only way to hold it together would be with big bands of unobtainium metal around the equator and most of the way to the poles to stop all the mass flying off into space.  So it's even more impossible.

Comment: "convert our moon into a supermax by converting it into a hollow sphere with it's interior filled with just cells and the inmates"..... withing 50 years? So you are expecting some population growth, averaging 79800 births per person per year, regardless of age or gender, from now on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spin doesn't work for me**

Spin creates artificial gravity, true. But the complexity is a mess. To keep every cell at 1G...

- The floor of every cell must be oriented away the axis of rotation, which I'll assume is the lunar polar axis. Remember that the moon does rotate, it just rotates to keep the same face toward Earth (time to rotate once = time to orbit once).
- From the north pole to the south pole you'd need floors, like the floors in a building. And each floor is rotating at its own speed because the rotation needed for 1G at the equator is different than the rotation needed at the poles.
- From the near-surface outer ring to the core of the moon you also need floors — a series of concentric rings. And the rings near the center of the moon must spin a lot faster than the rings near the surface to generate the same G. OK! Now we have independent floors north-to-south and rings surface-to-core, and every slice of the onion is spinning at a different speed to maintain 1G.
- Which means the moon just became a whomping big gyroscope doing heaven only knows what — but I'm sure it'll screw up the moon's orbit. Nope, I can't prove it. But I'm sure of it.
- And to make things worse, you can kinda move along the polar axis (at or near zero-G!) so long as you figure out how to spin like a top slower and slower as you descend from a pole to the center. But it's a bit harder from the surface to the core, where you'd need something like a long pair of slots at each ring with a "horizontal elevator" in each slot that could move to accelerate or decelerate into the appropriate ring.

That's awfully complex and, like I said, I think the moon would have a tough go with it.

**Magnetics?**

But, what if every inmate is required to wear clothing with a magnetic micro-mesh? It's not the same as gravity, but it might be close enough. This also has complexities because rather than pushing against the floor you're really pushing against your clothing. Make it a skin-tight suit (popular in sci-fi, right?) and it might even be believable. However, while this might benefit arm & leg muscles, etc. It wouldn't do anything for your heart or circulatory system, which would atrophy in the reduced gravity.  And you might have enough magnetism to interfere with the Van Allen Radiation Belts... So... maybe not magnetics.

**What if we spin the cells independently?**

OK, let's get back to spinning for a sec. Let's assume the infrastructure of the prison doesn't move at all. Only the individual cells spin. Each cell could be oriented to spin to preserve lunar inertia. But we wouldn't be talking about your average 10x10 style cell here, because that wouldn't be a whole lot different from taking a ride in a clothes dryer (we've all done that, right?).  So your cells are fairly large, suites really, to ensure a smooth spin.  OK, this is yucky, too. The mechanics behind that are almost worse than just spinning on the lunar axis. And I don't even want to think about getting food to the inmates without having to spin down the cells to do it. Ugh.

**OK, how about a bit of technobabble?**

Let's invent gravity plating. Electromagnetically controlled density that simulates mass and, therefore, gravity... Or maybe you've brought in neutron star material to make the floor plates. It's pure fiction, but it also has a problem. The gravity at the center of a sphere is zero — and we just made it non-zero thanks to the gravity plating. In fact, keeping all those inmates at 1G would raise the "apparent mass" of the moon to something that, well, in an outrageous XKCD kind of way, might make it implode into a micro black hole.

**Which brings up the real point of my answer, call this the TL;DR part**

You can't do it. It's not an issue of finding a way to achieve it. You obviously can spin the cells in a way to get the artificial gravity. It's the *consequences* that are the problem. You're dealing with a scale where even the smallest forces are a really big deal. Just the heat generated from all that spinning would proverbially ignite the surface of the moon like a second sun. Any energy-type-thing you add to reduce the heat (like magnets rather than bearings and a perfect vacuum) cause problems (like ripping out the fillings from people's teeth and causing the moon to implode from the vacuum force).

And then there's the need to discharge enough static electricity to power every household on Earth. All those rotating floors and rings... it's a giant generator. Even if the infrastructure is non-metalic/non-magnetic, you still have a bazillion miles of wire for lights, heating, etc. everywhere... all spinning at different speeds....

All of which would be detectable by the aliens from who knows how many parsecs away.... And they think imprisonment is barbaric. And they just noticed why you're lit up like an intergalactic Christmas tree with crazy EM radiation, heat, and gravity.

I can't think of a solution that doesn't have massive consequences that would result in a high-quality Hollywood disaster movie.

It was fun to think about... but wouldn't freezing them for their sentences be easier?

Answer (score 2):

#### Spin them.

You want to spin their cells around such that the moons gravity (down) plus the spin centrifugal force (outwards) adds up to one G (diagonally down and outwards ish).

Yes this results in a tilted cell cell if gravity needs to be normal to the floor. We can build ramps so this should be a non issue.

You would want to do a whole group of cells together rather than spin each individual block, as a strong gravity gradient would be disorienting, and the noise from a machine that close to your cell would be quite loud. Plus this way each cell only needs a tilted floor, rather than trying to curve a cell floor.

However were I in this prison and with zero hope for release back on earth id elect to be kept in 1/6th g - as far as we know the human body still works fine in those gravity levels, movement is 6 times easier, the mattress is 6 times softer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use lead garments. Each inmate will wear 5 times his/her/their own weight and you will claim the problem solved. After all, it does provide some excercise and is not like they will ever return. And the human rights organizations will be satisfied, since they do not *really* care, as the other conditions pretty much equal to torture anyway - $2 m^3$ per person is a cubicle $1m\times 1m\times 2m$, quite a coffin...